# How can I make the &lt; and &gt; actually become < and > in an innerText and innerHTML combination to make plain text?

Tags: javascript, html

If I have standalone less than signs, greater than signs, or ampersands in the `<xmp>` replacement using JavaScript, it treats them as &lt; and &gt; and &amp; respectively. I also want to keep HTML escaped entities, but not escape the < and >. Here's the replacement on top and the actual, deprecated `<xmp>`. That is, if it's even possible.

```js
var a = document.getElementById("xmp").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("xmp").innerText = a
```

```css
#xmp {
    white-space: pre;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<!-- The JavaScript xmp replacement - it doesn't show the greater than sign properly as it is entity escaped. I also need to keep the entities normal without being unescaped. -->
<div id="xmp">Foo bar              foo bar <a>this is xmp. &lt;</a> ></div>
  <!-- what <xmp> is like - DON'T USE THIS! -->
  <xmp>Foo bar              foo bar <a>this is xmp. &lt;</a> ></xmp>
```

Comment: When you assign to `innerText`, it treats it literally. When you assign to `innerHTML`, it's parsed as HTML.

Comment: @Barmar And how would I fix that though? I'm not the most experienced in JavaScript, so I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused here, you can't have an unescaped < or > inside of HTML. Your `<div>` is not valid HTML and browser simply escapes these tags for you

```js
var a = document.getElementById("orig").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("xmp").innerText = a;
document.querySelector("xmp").innerHTML = a;

var clone = document.getElementById("orig").cloneNode(true);
document.querySelector("xmp:nth-of-type(2)").appendChild(clone);
```

```css
body
{
  white-space: pre;
}
div {
    white-space: pre;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
original html:

<div id="orig">Foo bar              foo bar <a>this is xmp. &lt;</a> ></div>

text from original html:

<div id="xmp"></div>

HTML copy from original into &lt;XMP&gt;:
<xmp></xmp>
original clone appended into &lt;XMP&gt;:
<xmp></xmp>
&lt;XMP&gt; with hard coded (invalid html) text:
<xmp>Foo bar              foo bar <a>this is xmp. &lt;</a> > (invalid HTML)</xmp>
```

Comment: Right. The browser links > to &gt; and < to &lt; because it doesn't see them as correct HTML unless used as a tag, right? If it is, I could just close the xmp replacement, and shove a <code> in to have &lt; inside being escaped.

Comment: Instead of links, escapes. I can't edit the comment anymore..

Comment: Yes, that's correct. A combination of `<pre><code></code></pre>` is a currently recommended method, because `<xmp>` was removed from HTML5 specs.